# Get dynamic Key and value from json file

Tags: java, json

I have json files that contain a dynamic part and static part, my problem is in the dynamic part because I can't get the keys so I change to create a java class to get the  keys.

My file is like this :

```
[
{
    "data": {
        "1801": "1801_13",
        "293954": "293954_1",
        "293985": "noir",
        "294071": "294071_3",
        "ean":  "5035915032563",
         "Nature": "450"            
    },

    "creation_date": "2018-08-28T12:25:06.638Z",
    "update_date": "2018-08-28T12:32:55.640Z",
   },

 {
    "data": {
        "2633": "1801_13",
        "293954": "293954_1",
        "ean":  "5035236232070",
        "Nature": "301"             
    },

    "creation_date": "2018-08-28T12:25:06.638Z",
    "update_date": "2018-08-28T12:32:55.640Z",
   }  ]
```

data : dynamic part, and in this part I have two static keys (ena and nature) and the others keys are dynamic like this example.

I created this java class :

```
    package routines;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.*;

public class getKeyFromFile {




        public static void main(String filepath) throws ParseException, JSONException {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

            try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader( filepath));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)obj ;


            printJSON((JSONObject) jsonObject);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException ioe) {

            }       
        }
            public static void printJSON(JSONObject jsonObj) {
                for (Object keyObj : jsonObj.keySet()) {
                    String key = (String)keyObj;
                    Object valObj = jsonObj.get(key);
                    if (valObj instanceof JSONObject) {
                        // call printJSON on nested object
                        printJSON((JSONObject) valObj);
                    } else {
                        // print key-value pair
                        System.out.println("key : "+key);
                        System.out.println("value : "+valObj.toString());
                    }
                }
            }}
```

I get this error :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast
>   to org.json.JSONArray

Comment: Your json file seems to be malformed. You can check your json file for example [here](https://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things, first your json is malformed. Remove the comma at the end of the following line in both elements.

```
"update_date": "2018-08-28T12:32:55.640Z",
```

Second, the object is an array as you see in the error message. So, change your code to use JSONArray instead of JSONObject,

```
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
```

From there, you have to modify your print function to take `JSONArray` and use additional for loop to traverse through the loop. Something like this,

```
for (Object json : jsonArray) {
    printJSONOBject((JSONObject) json)
}

private void printJSONOBject(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    for (Object keyObj : jsonObject.keySet()) {
        String key = (String) keyObj;
        Object valObj = jsonObject.get(key);
        if (valObj instanceof JSONObject) {
            printJSONOBject((JSONObject) valObj);
        } else {
            System.out.println(key + " : " + valObj);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you techtabu :)
This code runs but it copy all me file.
i don't want to see the object data in my result.
I want :

```
1801  : 1801_13,
    293954: 293954_1,
    293985: noir,
    294071: 294071_3,
    ean   :  5035915032563,
    Nature: 450  ,
    creation_date: 2018-08-28T12:25:06.638Z,
    update_date: 2018-08-28T12:32:55.640Z
```

And for the second line  :

```
2633: 1801_13,
    293954: 293954_1,
    ean:    5035236232070,
    Nature: 301             
    creation_date: 2018-08-28T12:25:06.638Z,
    update_date: 2018-08-28T12:32:55.640Z,
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to print each json key and value. Point of note though. If you have questions on answer, you should ask it in comments under the answer and/ or update your original question. Because, first you are not providing an answer to your question. Second, I won't be notified unless you comment under my answer.

Comment: Sorry, i'm begginner in stackoverflow.  thanks your for your help, your solution fixed my problem.